# How to find the project root when creating an nx plugin

Tags: typescript, nrwl, nomachine-nx

I am currently building my first nx plugin and I am trying to add a target to the project.json and also add a file to the root of the project. I am currently passing the project name as a string to my generator.

```
export default async function (tree: Tree, options: {project: string}) {  
const projectConfiguration = readProjectConfiguration(tree, options.project);
  
  updateProjectConfiguration(tree, options.project, {
    ...projectConfiguration,
    targets: {
      ...projectConfiguration.targets,
      myExecutor: {
        executor: '@package/my-executor',
      },
    },
  }); 

  generateFiles(tree, path.join(__dirname, 'files/projectFiles'), projectConfiguration.root, {
    ...fileReplacementOptions
  })
};
```

When using this generator in an nx project before version 14, updateProjectConfiguration adds the target but removes the root key. When using this generator on a project > 14 projectConfiguration.root is undefined. This makes sense since the root key does not get added anymore when creating a project. What i found is this pull request which seems to confirm that https://github.com/nrwl/nx/pull/9977

Now I am wondering how I can make my plugin compatible to older nx versions and also how to find the root folder of a project. Especially when providing a project name like project-folder-project1-nested which root path would be /libs/project-folder/project1-nested.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating i found out that the issue was caused by installing the plugin locally which seemed to use the nx version from the plugin workspace instead of the nx version of the workspace the plugin was installed in. I only noticed this after installing the plugin from npm instead of locally.